# Avoid NULL value in CASE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case

How to avoid NULL values in CASE and SUM by P.Id. Problem is that i have more than one DPB.ProductTypeId in DPB table

```
SELECT  P.[Id], 
        CASE 
        WHEN DPB.ProductTypeId = 1 THEN SUM(DPB.BonusAmount)
        END AS [CasinoBonus]
FROM Player P           
JOIN PlayerBonus DPB ON P.[Id] = DPB.[PlayerId]
group by P.[Id],DPB.ProductTypeId
```

Comment: add some sample data and your expected output. and also add what issue you are facing.

Comment: `sum` already ignores null values.

Comment: If i put sum i got two rows, one with summarized values and one NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use case when inside sum

```
 SELECT  P.[Id], 
            sum(CASE 
            WHEN DPB.ProductTypeId = 1 THEN DPB.BonusAmount
            else 0
            END) AS [CasinoBonus]
    FROM Player P           
    JOIN PlayerBonus DPB ON P.[Id] = DPB.[PlayerId]
    where P.[Id] is not null and DPB.[PlayerId] is not null
    group by P.[Id],DPB.ProductTypeId
```

Comment: Your `CASE` expression might need an `ELSE 0` case.

Answer (score 1):

The `case` should be the argument to the `sum()`.  You query should look like this:

```
SELECT P.[Id], 
       SUM(CASE WHEN DPB.ProductTypeId = 1 THEN DPB.BonusAmount
           END) AS [CasinoBonus]
FROM Player P JOIN
     PlayerBonus DPB
     ON P.[Id] = DPB.[PlayerId]
GROUP BY P.[Id];
```

Note that you don't want `DPB.ProductTypeId` in the `GROUP BY`.

That said, you may simply want:

```
SELECT P.[Id], 
       SUM(DPB.BonusAmount) AS [CasinoBonus]
FROM Player P LEFT JOIN
     PlayerBonus DPB
     ON P.[Id] = DPB.[PlayerId] AND 
        DPB.ProductTypeId = 1
GROUP BY P.[Id];
```

Moving the condition to the `WHERE` clause removes the need for the `CASE` entirely.  The `LEFT JOIN` keeps all players, even those that don't have that product type.